# Azure Redis Cache suddenly empty?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-redis-cache

I have an Azure Redis Cache that I've been happily using but all of a sudden it bombed everything out of it's store and was empty. Has anyone experienced this before?

As an overview of the setup:

Basic 1GB tier.

Oldest data in there was 2 days ago. 
Max-memory policy = `volatile-lru`

Data persistence = N/A due to package level

I can re-add data back into the empty cache but I can't understand where the previous data could have gone?

Could this be down to a simple hiccup server-side causing data to drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the Basic tier, which means it's not persistent and has no replication or failover. To prevent issues like this, you'd need either Standard or Premium tier.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help David. So, essentially could the cache just drop out at any given moment on Basic?

Comment: @scgough that's how Redis works: it's in-memory storage, and as you very well know memory is volatile. Redis supports persistency on disk, but on Azure you need an higher tier than Basic.